# Best approach to find whether a scientific research paper has human trials/human testing or no

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to know the best way to know if a paper has human trials/test subjects/testing. Was thinking of searching for some keywords in the paper like "Human", "Trials" etc.

The method I tried gave me a lot of false positives

Comment: Hi @ChaitanyaMalhotra, welcome to the site. You could try with a solution based on large language models (LLM), like ChatGPT or Llama-2. They tend to be good at understanding language and answering simple questions about it.